# Where to execute an external API call that fills Django Model information

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Giving next Django model:

```
class Expedition(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='expeditions')
```

I wish to expose an endpoint which will be used in the frontend in order to create an Expedition, but the **code** is retrieved from an external API call.

I've tried to override the **perform_create** method in the ModelViewSet adding the external API call and then checking if *response.status_code == 200* or not, but the serializer's **create** method is always called with *code = ''*.

How can I manage the API call?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but one way to run code that uses a Django model outside of the context of the server is to use "manage shell" to start a shell.  There is probably a way to do this as a python app too.

Comment: I want to call an external API and fill a project's model field, but I need to return an error status code to my frontend if the request fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do something similar to this for the search service at work.  It's a django rest application that converts query params into a Solr API call.  The request handling is like this:

- Define a `get` handler for the view, which executes the below
- Use a custom DRF serializer to convert the query params to their equivalents for Solr search
- Define a `solr` client to wrap `pysolr` for specific things we need to override/re-implement, and expose a method for handling the search
- Use the solr client search method to query the Solr API with the query
- Process the results with business logic
- Return as JSON

These are all done inside the GET and POST handlers of the `APIView` subclass.

You could do something similar.

I would suggest at least the following:

1. Check the API's terms of service to ensure they allow third party storage and replication of the data.  If it does allow you, then continue on.  If it doesn't, then find some other service to use.  Be a good netizen.
2. Implement a client that abstracts away using the third party API into a series of useful methods.  I like how the API of the `requests` package is structured.
3. Re-implement the GET/POST/etc handlers in the view as necessary